# Problema en declaracion de documento XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Creo un documento XML desde código, y necesito que en la declaración se vea de esta manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Con el código que escribí solo muestra la versión, ¿Como puedo hacer para que muestre la codificación?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Mi código:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"); ;
```

Comment: Cuando hagas esta clase de preguntas, por favor aclara bien el codigo que estas usando. mas alla que el problema "parezca" claro, yo no se si es que no agregaaste la declaracion al XML, estas grabando por error otro XML, o que esta pasando.. esas dos lineas de codigo no dicen nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aquí tienes un ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

    public static void Main() {

    // Create and load the XML document.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string xmlString = "<book><title>Oberon's Legacy</title></book>";
    doc.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));

    // Create an XML declaration. 
    XmlDeclaration xmldecl;
    xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",null,null);
    **xmldecl.Encoding="UTF-8";**
    xmldecl.Standalone="yes";     

   // Add the new node to the document.
   XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
   doc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);

   // Display the modified XML document 
  Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

  }
}
```

espero que sea de tu ayuda un saludo

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco lo que has hecho? Para realizar una buena respuesta (no simplemente pegar código) mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 4):

El problema probablemente es que no estás añadiendo la declaración a tu documento. Debes hacerlo con `AppendChild` o `InsertBefore`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDeclaracion);
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("raiz");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(root);
xmlDoc.Save(@"c:\pruebaxml.xml");
```

Answer (score -3):

Asi funciono perfecto (No estaba agregando la declaracion lo hize con el metodo InsertBefore):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",null);
                XmlElement FacturaElectronica = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "FacturaElectronica", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                xmlDoc.AppendChild(FacturaElectronica);
                xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaracion, FacturaElectronica);
```

Comment: Efrain.. tenes una respuesta aceptada que no se sabe si soluciona tu problema. otra respuesta que es la copia de una respuesta anterior (la de Pikoh) y en tu pregunta ni siquiera esta claro si ese es el problea o no (ya que no se sabe, si no que suponen) que no agregabas la cabecera. Podrias ordenar todo este lio? tenes reputacion suficiente como para saber como funciona esto.

Comment: @gbianchi estas seguro que es una copia de una respuesta anterior , si quieres criticar  y hacer observaciones TE INVITO A ANALIZAR BIEN antes de comentar ...Saludos

Comment: Te invito a que lo conversemos en el [chat]